# Автозавершение в VS Code при написании кода на JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio-code

Есть файл подключенный в `index.html` через `script src="`. В нем есть  объект:

```
const PS_Name = function(){
    // this.data = "";
}

PS_Name.prototype = {
    Init: function(){
    },
    Worker: function(){
    }
}

const PS_Name_Object = new PS_Name();
```

Как мне обратиться к методам этого объекта из другого объекта, который так же подключен в `index.html` через `script src=""`?
Конечно, я могу тупо посмотреть в первый файл на имя метода и написать его:

```
PS_Name_Object.Worker();
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы VS Code понимал, что я обращаюсь именно к этому объекту и тем самым он смог бы делать автозавершение? Чтобы мне не вспоминать точное название методов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы `IntelliSense` в js файлах, нужно добавить файл `jsconfig.json`.

Например со следующим содержанием:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    }
}
```

Подробнее в справке: [JavaScript in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson)