# VS code при использовании 'let', 'class' и других команд ES6 выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Друзья, я работаю на Ubuntu. Установлен последний Node, последняя версия Visual Studio Code. Пишу код на JavaScript, но не могу использовать команды ES6 - let, const, class. Получаю следующую ошибку `SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`
Переустановки не помогают. На точно таких же машинах у коллег все работает без проблем. Все настройки по умолчанию. Кто сталкивался и как решили проблему?

Comment: _not yet supported outside strict mode_ - данное сообщение указывает, что нужно добавить `"use strict"`

Comment: @Grundy не помогает

Comment: тогда нужно проверить версии node и установленных пакетов

Comment: @Grundy 9.0.0 версия. Пробовал и другие. У коллег все аналогично, но у них работает без ошибок.

Comment: studio code может ссылать на старую версию

Comment: Как проверить и поправить?

Comment: попробуй открыть консоль самой студии и проверить версию, это раз. Открыть настройки студии и поискать в них строки связанные с node, это два

Comment: Все совпадает с актуальными версиями

Comment: и в настройках и в консоли?

Comment: Да, везде все ок

Comment: Возможно поможет ответ из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777716/186999)

Comment: Уже переустановил Ubuntu. У меня и node стала некорректно работать, не получалось поправить ничего. Сейчас все работает хорошо.